# cron is not working when i install plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created custom plugin, in that i have added functions for the cron job, when i installed and activated plugin it doesn't call the cron functions, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? 
here i have added my functions for it

```
function myplugin_schedule_cron() {
    echo "sdsdsd12";
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('myplugin_cron'))
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'myplugin_cron');
}

function myplugin_cron_function() {
    // see if fires via email notification
    wp_mail('test@gmail.com', 'Cron Worked', date('r'));
}

add_action('wp', 'myplugin_schedule_cron');
add_action('myplugin_cron', 'myplugin_cron_function');
```

Comment: The documentation suggests you use an activation hook instead of the wp action. You could try that. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Comment: thank @Mr.Me i will refer that doc